Exploring the Range and Properties of a Restricted Functional Operator Between Dual Spaces
Let $ Y $ be a subspace of a normed space $ X $. For $ x^* \in X^* $, define the operator $ R(x^*) = x^*|Y $, where $ x^*|Y $ is the restriction of $ x^* $ to $ Y $ (i.e., $ x^*|Y: Y \to \mathbb{R} $). We consider the map $ R: X^* \to Y^* $, where $ Y^* $ is the dual space of $ Y $.
I want to prove that $ R $ is a bounded linear operator and then show that $ R[B_{X^*}[0,1]] = B_{Y^*}[0,1] $, where $ B_{X^*}[0,1] $ and $ B_{Y^*}[0,1] $ are the closed unit balls in $ X^* $ and $ Y^* $, respectively.
My progress:
1.Proving that $ R $ is a bounded linear operator
To show that $ R $ is linear:
$
R(\lambda x^*_1 + x^*_2) = (\lambda x^*_1 + x^*_2)|Y = \lambda x^*_1|Y + x^*_2|Y = \lambda R(x^*_1) + R(x^*_2),
$
which confirms linearity.
To show boundedness:
$
\|R(x^*)\|_{Y^*} = \sup_{\|y\|_Y \leq 1} |R(x^*)(y)| = \sup_{\|y\|_Y \leq 1} |x^*(y)|.
$
Since $ x^* \in X^* $, it holds that $ \|x^*\|_{X^*} = \sup_{\|x\|_X \leq 1} |x^*(x)| $. Clearly, restricting $ x $ to $ y \in Y $ satisfies $ \|y\|_Y \leq \|x\|_X $. Thus, $ \|R(x^*)\|_{Y^*} \leq \|x^*\|_{X^*} $, ensuring boundedness.
2.To prove $ R[B_{X^*}[0,1]] = B_{Y^*}[0,1] $, we first show $ R[B_{X^*}[0,1]] \subseteq B_{Y^*}[0,1] $. For any $ x^* \in B_{X^*}[0,1] $, its restriction $ R(x^*) = x^*|Y $ defines a functional in $ Y^* $, and since $ \|x^*\|_{X^*} \leq 1 $, it follows that $ \|R(x^*)\|_{Y^*} \leq 1 $. Thus, $ R(x^*) \in B_{Y^*}[0,1] $.
For the reverse inclusion, let $ y^* \in B_{Y^*}[0,1] $. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $ x^* \in B_{X^*}[0,1] $ such that $ x^*|Y = y^* $. Hence, $ y^* = R(x^*) $, proving $ B_{Y^*}[0,1] \subseteq R[B_{X^*}[0,1]] $. Combining both inclusions, we conclude $ R[B_{X^*}[0,1]] = B_{Y^*}[0,1] $.
This is a rough idea of how I think the solution should proceed, but since this is a new field for me, I am unsure about the details I need to include in order to achieve a mathematically complete proof.

I am not sure what you mean by  $|y|_Y\le |x|_X$. You take the supremum over all elements of $Y$ which is less or equal to to the supremum over all elements of $X$. The rest looks good :)
